# Redmine Project files form Server Displaying actual html code instead of web page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, redmine, shared-hosting

When i browse my redmine url as http://redmine.mydomain.com it opens download dialogue box and that main page is saved instead of redering html

When i do http://redmine.mydomain.com/login it shows the html code of the login page instead of displaying login page.

It was working fine before 3-4 days. What is wrong all of a sudden? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using apache as a proxy?
Make sure you are not modifying the ContentType header with some AddType or Header directive.

On firefox 11 you can open the Web Console (**Ctr-Shift-K**), open http://redmine.mydomain.com/login and see the **Content-Type** of the response.

You should be receiving something like: **Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8**.

You can also try making the request directly to your rack server, if you're using thin or mongrel, and see if you also get the same Content-Type.